# Java DataOutputStream reading value issue

Tags: java

who can say what is the problem?

```
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(hostname, port);
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
String value = "состав";
os.writeBytes( value);
```

it returns "A>AB02" instead of "состав" , but it works fine with english words , i have tried to encode and decode value but result hasn't changed

Comment: You might want to use `writeUTF()`, not `writeBytes()`.

Comment: encoding and decoding are quite different than what you're doing. That would definitely work, but you'd need to know how many bytes your sending.

Comment: If you look at the javadoc for writeBytes, "Each character in the string is written out, in sequence, by discarding its high eight bits." So you could use `writeChars` which won't discard any of the bits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `Locale` object for `Russia` while writing to the stream.

Replace

```
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
String value = "состав";
os.writeBytes( value);
```

with

```
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
String value = "состав";
ps.printf(new Locale("ru"), "%s", value);
```